# Count the number of CPU cores using pthread_setaffinity_np

Tags: c, linux, cpu-cores

Just trying to devise an experimental method to count the number of CPU cores available on a system by setting the thread affinity for each core until it reaches an error (EINVAL "Invalid argument"). Definitely not recommended for production systems!

The method seems to work but are there any obvious pitfalls or reliability issues?

**cpu.c**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int GetNumberCPUs_Experimental() {
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    int cores = 0, max_cores = 1024;

    for (; cores < max_cores; cores++) {
        CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
        CPU_SET(cores, &cpuset);
        if (pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset) == EINVAL) break;
    }
    return cores;
}

int main() {
    printf("CPU(s): %ld\n", sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN));
    printf("CPU(s): %d (Experimental)\n", GetNumberCPUs_Experimental());
    return 0;
}
```

[image: cpu]

Comment: More usual is to parse `/proc/cpuinfo` and count the cores. Also, you can get clock speed, cache line size, numa info, etc for each core. When trying to _do_ something useful, this data can help decide how to map a heterogeneous mix of threads to cores.